# What is the best way to store large amounts of text data for lazycolumn elements?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, store

I am writing an application with a dialog system. Dialogues are formed as sequences of cards with specific text. They may alternate or repeat.

The card consists of an id, an image and text. When loading data, depending on the id, the required card will be displayed.

My question is what is the best way to store this data?

I'm guessing 3 options:

1. Store data in data classes and text in strings.xml
2. Store data in xml format and parse data using xml parser
3. Store room database data

Which method is the most practical and preferred in this case?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the three options you provided yourself would work perfectly fine!

To choose in between them you have to answer one simple question: Are you trying to create a dynamic system, in which you can create and delete cards or is it going to be static data?

Rephrased: Is the effort of implementing everything using a local database worth it, if you're just going to display static data?

I personally would implement it using a database, as I'd want to at least have the option to eventually do everything dynamically. Also: `strings.xml` is for static UI elements only IMO.

Hope this helped! Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Data in text form will be stored statically and will not change during the use of the application. For me personally, the easiest way to implement data storage is in a date class. It’s just that I don’t have much experience in development, so I doubt which option to choose

Comment: The easiest way for you to implement a _static_ data set is saving your text in the `strings.xml`, as you can simply access it via `R.Strings.[...]`. If the text is static, I guess your images and _the cards order_ are too - so you can just set that programmatically too. The cleaner way, as mentioned above, however definitely is the database-approach. (It's not too hard and there are tons of tutorials online; I'd recommend starting with the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Comment: Great! I have already worked with the room database, so I can easily implement this option. Now I'm a little more confident. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go static. One option could be to store them in an enum class. Since the data will be constant

```
enum class MyCards(val id: String, @DrawableRes val image: Int, @StringRes val text: Int) {
    CARD_1("1", R.drawable.card1_image, R.string.card1_text),
    CARD_2("2", R.drawable.card2_image, R.string.card2_text),
    CARD_3("2", R.drawable.card3_image, R.string.card3_text)
}
```

Enums can be serialized and deserialized, therefore you can work with them in a database should that need arise later.